# cuda unified memory: memory transfer behaviour

Tags: pointers, memory, cuda

I am learning cuda, but currently don't access to a cuda device yet and am curious about some unified memory behaviour. As far as i understood, the unified memory functionality, transfers data from host to device on a need to know basis. So if the cpu calls some data 100 times, that is on the gpu, it transfers the data only during the first attempt and clears that memory space on the gpu. (is my interpretation correct so far?)

**1** Assuming this, is there some behaviour that, if the programmatic structure meant to fit on the gpu is too large for the device memory, will the UM exchange some recently accessed data structures to make space for the next ones needed to complete to computation or does this still have to be achieved manually?

**2** Additionally I would be grateful if you could clarify something else related to the memory transfer behaviour. It seems obvious that data would be transferred back on fro upon access of the actual data, but what about accessing the pointer? for example if I had 2 arrays of the same UM pointers (the data in the pointer is currently on the gpu and the following code is executed from the cpu) and were to slice the first array, maybe to delete an element, would the iterating step over the pointers being placed into a new array so access the data to do a cudamem transfer? surely not.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as i understood, the unified memory functionality, transfers data from host to device on a need to know basis. So if the cpu calls some data 100 times, that is on the gpu, it transfers the data only during the first attempt and clears that memory space on the gpu. (is my interpretation correct so far?)

The first part is correct: when the CPU tries to access a page that resides in device memory, it is transferred in main memory transparently. What happens to the page in device memory is probably an implementation detail, but I imagine it may not be cleared. After all, its contents only need to be refreshed *if* the CPU writes to the page *and if* it is accessed by the device again. Better ask someone from NVIDIA, I suppose.

> Assuming this, is there some behaviour that, if the programmatic structure meant to fit on the gpu is too large for the device memory, will the UM exchange some recently accessed data structures to make space for the next ones needed to complete to computation or does this still have to be achieved manually?

Before CUDA 8, no, you could not allocate more (*oversubscribe*) than what could fit on the device. Since CUDA 8, it is possible: pages are faulted in and out of device memory (probably using an LRU policy, but I am not sure whether that is specified anywhere), which allows one to process datasets that would not otherwise fit on the device and require manual streaming.

> It seems obvious that data would be transferred back on fro upon access of the actual data, but what about accessing the pointer?

It works exactly the same. It makes no difference whether you're dereferencing the pointer that was returned by `cudaMalloc` (or even `malloc`), or some pointer *within* that data. The driver handles it identically.

Comment: maybe my example for the last question wasn't so clear, I don't mean to free the memory in the pointer. ie there are 2 arrays with the same UM pointers but form the first I wish the slice out a few. The actual data is not meant to be freed, just some pointer play is happening. Would you happen to know anything about such behaviour?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, I made no mention of freeing anything.

Comment: Sorry my visualisation of your response was weird, i think you verified what I thought would happen. Playing with pointers doesn't initiate any memory transfer between devices.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "playing with pointers". What triggers a "memory transfer" is a *page fault*, that is when you *dereference* a pointer to an address that is not currently *physically* in memory. Manipulating pointers as *values* does not trigger a page fault.

Comment: Doesn't the oversubscription capability depend on the compute capability rather than on the CUDA version (you obviously need a newer version of CUDA for the newest compute capability, but still)

Comment: ICBW, but I don't think it's related to compute capability. It'd guess it's a combination of hardware support (GPU needs to report page faults to the CPU) and driver support (driver needs to handle these page faults and trigger a page migration). Probably better to ask NVIDIA engineers.